# Kivy ScrollView is not able to scroll

Tags: python, kivy

This is the .py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


class Stack(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(0,100):
            b1 = Button(text=str(i+1),size_hint=(.1,.1))
            self.add_widget(b1)

class ScrollView(ScrollView):
    pass

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Stack()
    
GameApp().run()
```

And this is the .kV file:

```
<ScrollView>:
        Stack:
                size_hint:1,None
                height:4000
```

In the output I am getting the buttons but I am unable to scroll.

Comment: Your `GameApp` is not using any `ScrollView`. Your `GameApp` consists of a `Stack` widget with 100 `Buttons`, but no `ScrollView`. By the way,  defining a subclass `ScrollView` that extends a class of the same name `ScrollView` is a bad idea and can only lead to errors and confusion.

Comment: Please have a look at [**`ScrollView`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#managing-the-content-size-and-position) for proper usage. In addition to this you have to change `root` widget to get expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you are new please check this [link](https://youtu.be/AHjtJk2eKYo) for beginners guide.

The ScrollView only works if you put 1 widget on it with specific adjustments to size ofcourse.

Instead of this line

```
return stack()
```

You must return the scrollview widget and add the stack() layout on top. Even better you can modify your code like so

For .py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Stack(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(0,100):
            b1 = Button(text=str(i+1),size_hint=(.1,.1))
            self.add_widget(b1)

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()
    
GameApp().run()
```

.kv

```
<MainScreen>:
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_y: True
        do_scroll_y: False
        Stack:
                size_hint:1,None
                height:4000
```

I did not test the code but thats the logic of how the code can be. The rest you can check [here](https://youtu.be/AHjtJk2eKYo)